# How publish new post with XML RPC

Tags: c#, xml-rpc

I use WordPressSharp lib [link](https://github.com/abrudtkuhl/WordPressSharp) but in documentation i cannot find how i make publish new articles. By default new articles go in draft.

```
    var post = new Post {
    PostType = "post",
    Title = "My Awesome Post",
    Content = "<p>This is the content</p>",
    PublishDateTime = DateTime.Now
};

using (var client = new WordPressClient(new WordPressSiteConfig {
    BaseUrl = "http://mywordpress.com",
    Username = "admin",
    Password = "password",
    BlogId = 1
})) 
{
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(client.NewPost(post));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
Status = "publish";
```